# Playing with anonymous types

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

From Jon Skeet's wonderful book *C# In Depth, First Edition*:

```
class Film
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name={0}, Year={1}", Name, Year);
    }
}

var films = new List<Film>
{
    new Film {Name="Jaws", Year=1975},
    new Film {Name="Singing in the Rain", Year=1952},
    new Film {Name="Some Like It Hot", Year=1959},
    new Film {Name="The Wizard of Oz", Year=1939},
    new Film {Name="It's a Wonderful Life", Year=1946},
    new Film {Name="American Beauty", Year=1999},
    new Film {Name="High Fidelity", Year=2000},
    new Film {Name="The Usual Suspects", Year=1995}
};

Action<Film> print = film => { Console.WriteLine(film); };
films.ForEach(print);
films.FindAll(film => film.Year < 1960)
.ForEach(print);
films.Sort((f1, f2) => f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name));
films.ForEach(print);
```

A paragraph follows the above-listed snippet of code.

> The first half of listing 9.4 involves just setting up the data. I would have used an anonymous type, but it’s relatively tricky to create a generic list from a collection of anonymous type instances. (You can do it by *creating a generic method that takes an array
>   and converts it to a list of the same type, then pass an implicitly typed array into that
>   method.* An extension method in .NET 3.5 called ToList provides this functionality
>   too, but that would be cheating as we haven’t looked at extension methods yet!)

And the code snippet provided above, is listing 9.4 of the book that the paragraph refers to.

**My question:**
I am trying out the technique outlined in the above paragraph by hand (look at the italicized text) but I can't quite understand what he means.

I tried something like this but it isn't what he meant, I suppose, as it doesn't work (and I didn't expect it to):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ScratchPad
{

class Film
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name = {0}\tYear = {1}", 
            Name, Year);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ToList<Film>( new[]
        {
            new { Name = "North By Northwest", Year = 1959 },
            new { Name = "The Green Mile", Year = 1999},
            new { Name = "The Pursuit of Happyness", Year = 2006}
        }).ForEach( f => {Console.WriteLine(f);} );

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<T> ToList<T>(
        System.Collections.IEnumerable list)
    {
        var newList = new List<T>();

        foreach (var thing in list)
            if (thing is T)
                newList.Add((T)thing);

        return newList;

    }
}
```

}

**Note:** I know about the IEnumerable.ToList() extension method and have used it many times. I just want to try the technique outlined in the paragraph by hand.

Also, I'm intrigued by scenarios where anonymous types are used outside of Linq, as a syntactic convenience and one of such scenarios is given below. I can always use `dynamic` in C# 4 and accept an anonymous type as an argument and work with it knowing what I expect. I wish I could do that with C# 3. Something like below:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;

namespace PlayWithAnonType
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintThingy(new { Name = "The Secret", 
Genre = "Documentary", Year = 2006 });
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    static void PrintWhatever(dynamic whatever)
    {
        // the anonymous type's ToString() will print
        Console.WriteLine(whatever);
    }

    static void PrintThingy(dynamic thingy)
    {
        try
        {
            // I know what the thingy is
            Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}\tGenre = {1}\tYear = {2}",
                thingy.Name, thingy.Genre, thingy.Year);
        }
        catch(RuntimeBinderException ex)
        {
#pragma warning disable 0168
            Console.WriteLine("By thingy, I really meant film. 
Sorry, I should've clarified.");
#pragma warning restore 0168
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Edit**
They should have a tag named jon-skeet.

Comment: I know who's gonna win this question ;)

Comment: Would be very ironic if a question about Jon's book was asked, Jon asnwered is and some other person won lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To actually do it:

```
public void Main (string[] args)
{
    var films = ToList(new [] {
        new {Name = "Jaws", Year = 1975},
        new {Name = "Singing in the Rain", Year = 1952},
        new {Name = "Some Like It Hot", Year = 1959},
        new {Name = "The Wizard of Oz", Year = 1939},
        new {Name = "It's a Wonderful Life", Year = 1946},
        new {Name = "American Beauty", Year = 1999},
        new {Name = "High Fidelity", Year = 2000},
        new {Name = "The Usual Suspects", Year = 1995}
    }
    );


    films.ForEach(f => Console.Write(f.Name + " - " + f.Year));

}

public List<T> ToList<T> (IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return new List<T>(list);
}
```

As others have mentioned, I'm not sure how useful this is.  You do get intellisense and all that when you write it, so there's probably some typing savings, at least? :)

Comment: Heheh! Copycat. I could do that, too, if I felt like cheating from Reflector. :-)

But many thanks.

Comment: Tough one! Should the green checky come to you? Tough one. Real tough one. :-)

Comment: Glad for my first green checky :P  I actually wrote this up based on the question (no Reflector involved); I hadn't really thought about using anonymous types this way.  It's a pretty cool shortcut, actually.

Comment: I can't believe this is your first green checky. I think I know you. Aren't you that clever C++ chap from Channel 9?

Comment: Nope.  I'm a C# junkie through and through (so far).

Answer (score 8):

The point was that if we knew about `ToList` we'd have a way of creating the list without having our own `Film` type at all. It wasn't that we'd be able to mix an anonymous type with a `Film` type. In other words, we could do:

```
// The type of list will be List<T> where T is the anonymous type
var list = new[]
{
    new { Name = "North By Northwest", Year = 1959 },
    new { Name = "The Green Mile", Year = 1999},
    new { Name = "The Pursuit of Happyness", Year = 2006}
}.ToList();

list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.Year));
```

Glad you're enjoying the first edition, btw - hopefully it won't be too long before the second edition comes out :)

Comment: Still eagerly awaiting that 2nd edition, of which I regularly receive updates of... postponing. But I'm sure it'll be worth the wait!

Comment: @Abel: Ooh, I didn't know they were sending out postponement notices :( If it's any consolation, I've just received the first two post-first-proofread chapters, which means it really is getting close. I'm as eager to get it out as you are to receive it, I'm sure :)

Comment: Hi Jon, I do understand what life would be if we were able to use the ToList() extension method. I just want to try out the hack you mentioned, if ToList() did not exist at all.

<br />
I want some new lines, so let me try out some XHTML.
<br />

PS: Of course, I am loving the book. This is my second reading. The first one was a quick reading. This one's with trying out every little detail in the book. I just can't wait for the second edition. I'm conducting a 54 hour C# 4 training in my company and distributing copies to pop-quiz winners. :-)

Comment: @Water Cooler v2: The hack would basically be reimplementing ToList, that's all :) arootbeer's answer has the appropriate code.

Comment: I feel like an idiot! :-) I should've simply seen the implementation of ToList() extension in Reflector. Thanks so much, anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think what Jon is describing is actually very useful to you here. The only point he is making is that he would not normally create an entire class `Film` just for this example, if it weren't for the problems with creating a `List<AnonType>`.

**Edit:** Damn. Alright, this time I am leaving my answer here anyway :)